# matplotlib: how to change data point color based on it's boolean value consistently.

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a boolean numpy array using pcolormesh from matplotlib. If the cell value in the numpy array is True I would like to display it in green, otherwise I would like to display it in the red.

Here's the code snippet that I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy
from matplotlib import colors
matrix = numpy.array([[True, True, True]])
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green', 'red'], 'indexed')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(matrix, cmap=cmap, edgecolor='black', linestyle='-', lw=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I change my matrix to:
matrix = numpy.array([[False, False, False]])
All the cells are still green and not red.

[image]

Is there a way to consistently assign a boolean value to a specific color using ListedColormap? Ideally a False value would always be mapped to the color red and a True value would be always mapped to the color green.

I am using Python 2.7.6, Matplitlib version: 1.4.3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I found a way of solving this.

Basically I use the `set_bad` property of `colormaps` in matplotlib.

First I mask all the False occurrences in my numpy array as 'bad' data

```
matrix = numpy.ma.masked_where(matrix == False, matrix)
```

Secondly I create a ListedColormap with only the color green specified.

```
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green'])
```

Then I use the `set_bad` property of `colormaps` to set all the 'bad' data to red.

```
cmap.set_bad(color='red')
```

Here's the complete code example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy
from matplotlib import colors

# Example data
matrix = numpy.array([[True, False, False]])

# Mask the False occurences in the numpy array as 'bad' data
matrix = numpy.ma.masked_where(matrix == False, matrix)

# Create a ListedColormap with only the color green specified
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green'])

# Use the `set_bad` property of `colormaps` to set all the 'bad' data to red
cmap.set_bad(color='red')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(matrix, cmap=cmap, edgecolor='black', linestyle='-', lw=1)

plt.show()
```